# commandButton update attribute not working

Tags: ajax, primefaces, commandbutton

I have a commandButton which opens a dialog containing a table.

When the button is clicked the dialog pops out but it does not contain anything.

This is my code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="correctionsEntries" layout="block">

    <p:dataTable styleClass="dataTable" id="entriesTable" var="entry" value="#{bean.tableModel.items}">

        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <ui:repeat var="column" value="#{bean.tableModel.columns}" varStatus="colStatus">
                    <p:column  headerText="#{column.header}">
                    </p:column>
                </ui:repeat>
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>

        <c:forEach var="column" items="#{bean.tableModel.columns}">

            <c:choose>  
                <c:when test="${column.header eq 'Upload'}">
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton value="Upload" immediate="true" actionListener="#{bean.setSelectedRow(entry)}" oncomplete="PF('upload').show();" />

                        <p:dialog header="Upload" widgetVar="upload" height="10%" width="80%">
                            <p:messages binding="#{bean.component}" /> 
                            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.uploadCSV}" />
                        </p:dialog>
                    </p:column>
                </c:when>

                <c:when test="${column.header eq 'Export'}">
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton value="Download" immediate="true" ajax="false" actionListener="#{bean.setSelectedRow(entry)}">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{bean.downloadCSV()}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
                </c:when>

                <c:when test="${column.header eq 'Display'}">
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton id="displayButton" value="Display"
                            immediate="true"
                            action="#{tableBean.execute(entry)}"
                            update="displayTable"
                            oncomplete="PF('dialog').show();" />

                        <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Current data" widgetVar="dialog" height="80%" width="80%">

                            <p:dataTable styleClass="dataTable"
                                id="displayTable" var="tableDataVar"
                                value="#{tableBean.tableModel.data}"
                                tableStyle="width:auto;" resizableColumns="true">

                                <p:columns var="tableHeader" value="#{tableBean.tableModel.headers}">
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{tableHeader}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{tableDataVar[tableHeader]}" />

                                </p:columns>

                            </p:dataTable>

                        </p:dialog>
                    </p:column>
                </c:when>

                <c:when test="${column.header eq 'Test'}">
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton value="Test" immediate="true" ajax="false" actionListener="#{bean.setSelectedRow(entry)}">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{bean.testFilesDownload()}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
                </c:when>

                <c:otherwise>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{bean.tableModel.get(entry, column)}" />
                    </p:column>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:forEach>

    </p:dataTable>  

</h:panelGroup>
```

The table is displayed only after refreshing the page.

Comment: please show dialog code

Comment: Dialog code is right there (second tag).

Comment: check for js errors into browser console or backing bean errors into eclipse console

Comment: There are no errors

Comment: paste complete code if possible

Comment: I edited adding the complete code

Comment: This is not complete code. And it should be [mcve], not just 'complete

Comment: This is all I can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a dialog containing the table is created for each of the column from the parent table.

Therefore there are as many dialog as there are columns.

The fix for this was adding the dialog in a separate form, and referring it in the commandButton by specifying its path.

Comment: I had to wait 21h until I could